# How to map two longs to an integer (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary

I have two kinds of objects identified by a `long` and these objects should be mapped to column or row indices in a matrix of type `int`. There are thousands of objects to be mapped and only the combination of the IDs is unique (e.g. (1,1) -> 0; (1,2) -> 1; ... (2,2)->...)).

Is a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is `"long1<a separator>long2"` the way to go or are there better solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I would use `Map<Map<Long, Long>, Integer>`

Comment: Is it a fully populated matrix or a sparsely populated one? (ie do all the x,y have values?)

Comment: I wouldn't use a `long` if you can avoid it because its unrealistically large.  A full set of `int` x `int` keys would require around half a trillion GB of memory. A full set of `long` x `long` would require 18 trillion trillion times this. If you believe you need to have `long` x `long` keys I suggest you rethink your problem.

Comment: @Michael If there are just a few thousand objects, then you can follow Peter's advice and use ints instead of longs. You would save some memory this way (a long is twice as big in memory).

Comment: I should have expressed my question a bit differently. @Peter  and SoboLAN: I do not think that I need long x long keys. But I have existing entities coming from a database which are identified by a long as key and I want to map a combination of the two types to an ordinal int (and I know that I could create class therefore, but my question was more how to create the hash from the two longs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to create the hash from the two longs

You can create a hash from a long with

```
long l = ...
int hash = (int) ((l >> 32) ^ l);
```

for two longs you can combine there

```
long a = ..., b = ...
long l = a * 31 + b;
int hash = (int) ((l >> 32) ^ l);
```

Its not guaranteed to be unique, but it doesn't use any memory.

Answer (score 11):

Create an object that holds 2 longs and override the equals and hashcode methods. You can then use this as the key.

Answer (score 4):

Why you don't create an object to hold these two `long` variables.

```
class Key {
    private long var1;
    private long var2;
    boolean equals(Object o) {...}
    int hashCode() {...}
};
```